# How to set page title in an angular page?

Tags: angular

I have created an angular page and module and it does exactly what I wanted it to do. However the page title is CiviCRM and I want to change that.
How do I do that?

I have tried to set it in the javascript:

```
angular.module('myemma').config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/my-emma-accounts', {
    controller: 'MyemmaMyEmmaAccounts',
    templateUrl: '~/myemma/MyEmmaAccounts.html',
    title: 'MyEmma accounts',

    // If you need to look up data when opening the page, list it out
    // under "resolve".
    resolve: {
      accounts: function(crmApi) {
        return crmApi('MyEmmaAccount', 'get', {});
      }
    }
  });
});
```

However the code above does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: add this to the top of your main angular html template:

```
<h1 crm-page-title>{{ts('Hello')}}</h1>
```

More info:

- Documentation can be found in the [crmUi code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/750c4bb5c5e5d101ad43c1352b6f1ab82752b5d4/ang/crmUi.js#L985).
- This feature is in 4.7+ (although if you use it in 4.6 it won't crash - it just won't look as good).
- Note the support for setting document title seperately if you wish.